# How can I get a tunnelling link from an app deployed on GCP Shell?

Tags: python, socket.io, google-cloud-shell-editor

I've deployed a python app that uses SocketIO using the GCP Shell/Text editor as a backend server. I want to connect a flutter frontend. To do this, I need a tunnelling link, and I was wondering if anyone could help me find it, or, if there was another way to deploy python code so that I could get a tunnelling link?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH and port-forwarding to forward Cloud Shell instance ports to your host's ports.

The easiest way to do this is using [`gcloud cloud-shell ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/cloud-shell/ssh) with the (`gcloud`) [`--ssh-flag`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/cloud-shell/ssh#--ssh-flag) flag and the SSH (!) `-L` flag:

```bash
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --ssh-flag="-L {LOCAL}:localhost:{REMOTE}"
```

Where `{LOCAL}` is the local host's port and `{REMOTE}` is the port on the Cloud Shell instance.

Cloud Shell is provided as an easy way to access a Compute Engine instance and pre-installed tools (including `gcloud`). I'd discourage using it as a host for your server for anything other than testing.